# Changing $row values to integer decimals on PHP

Tags: php, json, api, row

I'm trying to recreate something like this: http://www.coincap.io/

It's working so far, but I'm having trouble to display the numbers as decimals (.0000). If I try to do it inside a cell (`<td><?= $row->price; ?></td>`, for example), it messes with my table layout. Is there a way to set individual objects to display decimals differently? 
Such as that price: .0000, volume: .00, and so on.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Market Cap</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
            <th>Supply</th>
            <th>24h(%)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php function compare($a, $b) {
            return intval($a->position24) - intval($b->position24);
        } 

        $json = file_get_contents('http://www.coincap.io/front');
        $data = json_decode($json);
        usort($data, 'compare'); 
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row->position24; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->long; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->price; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->mktcap; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->volume; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->supply; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->cap24hrChangePercent; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php) Here is a number_format sample.

```
echo number_format(110000,2); // 110,000.00
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how would that fit on my code?

Comment: here is for your price row ``<td><?= number_format($row->price, 2); ?><\td>``

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why it widens the columns though.